How to create a frequency variable from multiple response modalities in R?
I am working on a database in R that is the result of a questionnaire. I have a problem with some of the variables. Some questions are good and are assigned to one single variable, for example the question 17 had 4 possible answers and when I do table(d$v17) I obtain
 1   2   3   4 
328 100  12  22 

However, some questions, instead of being assigned to a single variable, have a variable made for each answer and no variable that regroups them all at once. This is happening to me with question 18, which is a question that allows multiple choice answers and has 11 modalities. Instead of having a variable v18 that would give me a result similar to what I have up there, I have 11 variables that go from v18_r1 to v18_r11, therefore I cannot do a table like I did for question 17.
The reason this bothers me is that I want to have all the values of question 18 in the same variable so that I can later use it in a tbl_summary in order to cross it with another variable.
The closest I got to resolving this was this bit of code (from ChatGPT) :
# Initialize a variable for the counts
count_result <- rep(0, 11)

# Loop through each row of the data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  # Check each column from v18_r1 to v18_r11 to see if the value is non-NA
  for (j in 1:11) {
    if (!is.na(d[i, paste0("v18_r", j)])) {
      count_result[j] <- count_result[j] + 1  # Increment the count for this option
    }
  }
}

# Display the result
count_result

However it only prints the frequency of each answer without having the 1, 2, 3, etc. above and I cannot use it in a tbl_summary.
In case it might be useful, here is what my variables look like when I use str(d) :
$ v18_r1            : int  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r2            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r3            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r4            : int  4 NA 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r5            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r6            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r7            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r8            : int  8 NA NA NA 8 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r9            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ v18_r10           : int  10 NA 10 NA 10 NA NA NA 10 NA ...
 $ v18_r11           : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

Thank you very much in advance to all.

Try sapply(d, table, useNA = "always").

There can be no variable that groups the questions since the answers given are not mutually exclusive. EG observation one has 1 for v18_r1 , 4 for v18_r4, 8 for v18_r8  and 10 for v18_r10. To get a table like v17, there should only be one response  for  v18_r1:v18_r11 for each observation. Since this is not the case, the questions in v18 cannot be collapsed

Thank you for your answer @Onyambu, I didn't know that. Even though to be honest, I still don't understand why there cannot be one big variable that counts how many answers have been ticked for each modality, it doesn't seem incompatible in my head... but I'm not very good at this.

You can retain all the related info in one column, but its just reads ugly ...
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
(example_start <- data.frame(
  V17 = 1:3,
  V18_r1 = c(1, NA, NA),
  V18_r2 = c(4, NA, NA),
  V18_r3 = c(NA, NA, 3)
))

name_and_val <- function(val) {
  glue("{dplyr::cur_column()}={val}")
}

(example_end <- mutate(rowwise(example_start),
  across(starts_with("v18_r"), name_and_val),
  V18 = paste0(pick(starts_with("V18_r")), collapse = ";")
) |>
  select(-starts_with("v18_r")))

results
table(example_end$V17)

1 2 3 
1 1 1 
> table(example_end$V18)

  V18_r1=1;V18_r2=4;V18_r3=NA  V18_r1=NA;V18_r2=NA;V18_r3=3 V18_r1=NA;V18_r2=NA;V18_r3=NA 
                            1                             1                             1 

does this help ?

Hello, thank you for your anwser @NirGraham
I am sorry, I don't understand how to apply this to my situation because for example for V18_r1 = c(1, NA, NA) I can't just paste the 1500 entries I have, I tried directly putting d$v18_r1 instead but it doesn't work
